# django error in import users.signals into apps.py in users app

Tags: python, django, signals

following is my settings.py installed app section

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    # third party
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'corsheaders',
    'crispy_forms',
    # local apps
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

following is my apps.py file content

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

following is my signal.py file content

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**init**.py file in users app is empty

when I run command python manage.py makemigrations it gives error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users.users'
and also it shows error "No module named users" in the following line in apps.py
import users.signals

my project directory sctructure screenshot is as shown in attached picture
[enter image description here][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNU7p.png
```

with reference to above django configuration/code  what correction in needed  to resolve error in apps.py so that no module named users is resolved and signals are loaded correctly for the users app

edit: as needed by another user for providing solution my current custom user model in development is as below

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .managers import CustomUserManager


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    CHOICES = (
        ('T', 'Teacher'),
        ('I', 'Institute'),
        ('S', 'Student'),
    )

    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Student(models.Model):
    user_student = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="student_account"
    )
    standard = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user_profile = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile"
    )
    location = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=140, default="Male", blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Profile of user: %s' % self.user_profile.email


class Teacher(models.Model):
    user_teacher = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="teacher_account"
    )
    years_of_Experience = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


class Institute(models.Model):
    user_institute = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Institute_account"
    )
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)


class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user_student_profile = models.OneToOneField(
        Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="student_profile"
    )
    is_disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Profile of Student: %s' % self.user_student_profile.user_student.email


class TeacherProfile(models.Model):
    user_teacher_profile = models.OneToOneField(
        Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="teacher_profile"
    )
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Profile of teacher : %s' % self.user_teacher_profile.user_teacher.email


class InstituteProfile(models.Model):
    user_institute_profile = models.OneToOneField(
        Institute, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="institute_profile"
    )
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Profile of Institute : %s' % self.user_institute_profile.user_institute.email
```

Comment: Could you Add ```'users'``` to ```INSTALLED_APPS``` and check.

Comment: As suggested changed INSTALLE_APPS section in settings.py from 'users.apps.UsersConfig',  to   'users', still it shows no module named users error but after deleting migrations files and database , re migrating it can start server. in Apps.py if entry is changed to import HelloDjangoUsersSite.users.signals then it does not show no module error but while running server it shows error  File "D:\djangoprojects\hellodjangousers\HelloDjangoUsersSite\users\apps.py", line 8, in ready
    import HelloDjangoUsersSite.users.signals
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'HelloDjangoUsersSite.users'

Comment: Could you post your entire project structure ?

Comment: directory structure  screenshot is available at https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNU7p.png HelloDjangoUsersSite is project containing settings.py and users is app containing apps.py

Comment: You are using a Custom User Model ```AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'```. Could you share your ```users.models.py``` code?

Comment: added current model in the edited question post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything looks fine. I think the reason for error is because of Order of apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Change your `INSTALLED_APPS` like this and check.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     # local apps
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
     
    # third party
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'corsheaders',
    'crispy_forms',
]
```

Comment: it still shows error in pycharm IDE and can  use command makemigrations, migrate and runserver however when project is opened is VS Code error is not shown so marking issues as resolved

Comment: May be because of improper configurations. There are a lot of questions in SO addressing issues where code works in one IDE and doesn't in other IDE. You can go through them. @Curious San